# Insufficient storage error message

Tags: storage, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have bought new Samsung Galaxy S7. And it has available space of 27 GB, though whenever I try to download app it shows insufficient storage error.
Please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

try to reboot, check your storage settings or try using google:

http://recomhub.com/blog/galaxy-s7-how-to-fix-insufficient-storage-available-message/

Answer (score 0):

Check your internal storage, It must be minimum free in order to install apps.
Can you send your storage details.